# Adding zeros to a string without generating a new variable

Tags: string, expression, stata

I am trying to add zeros to a string variable in such a way that all levels of the variables have same number of digits (assume `3`).

```
clear
input tina bina str4 pine 
1 10 "99" 
1 11 "99" 
2 11 "99" 
2 11 "99" 
3 12 "." 
4 12 "888" 
5 14 "88" 
6 15 "777" 
7 16 "77" 
8 17 "0" 
8 18 "7" 
end
```

I managed to do this by generating a new variable which stores the number of digits I need to add to each observation in order to reach `3`:

```
generate pi=3-strlen(pine)
replace pine= ("0"*pi) + pine if strlen(pine)<3
```

I wonder if there is a way to obtain the same result but without generating the variable?

I tried the following but it does not work :

```
replace pine= ("0"*(`=3-strlen(pine)')) + pine if strlen(pine)<3
```

Probably I am not so clear about what happens when I evaluate expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach does not work because it evaluates the expression for the first observation only:

```
. display `= 3 - strlen(pine)'
1
```

The single quotes are not required:

```
replace pine = ("0" * (3-strlen(pine) ) ) + pine if strlen(pine) < 3

     +--------------------+
     | tina   bina   pine |
     |--------------------|
  1. |    1     10    099 |
  2. |    1     11    099 |
  3. |    2     11    099 |
  4. |    2     11    099 |
  5. |    3     12    00. |
     |--------------------|
  6. |    4     12    888 |
  7. |    5     14    088 |
  8. |    6     15    777 |
  9. |    7     16    077 |
 10. |    8     17    000 |
     |--------------------|
 11. |    8     18    007 |
     +--------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I know there is already an accepted answer, but I wanted to throw out my suggestion. This is maybe a little bit simpler than the other answer and is straightforward to explain. You just want to replace a string variable of real numbers with leading zeros and keep it as a string. You can easily do this by running:

```
replace pine = string(real(pine),"%03.0f")
```

Depending on your goal this is maybe better than the previous answer, because it maintains your missing value as missing and not add zeros to it. Hopefully this helpful.